# Using "value" as an identifier in C#

Tags: c#

In writing short helper functions, I often find myself wanting to use the variable identifier "value" as an argument. It seems as though Visual Studio compiles this just fine, and has no complaints, when I do this:

```
public void MyMethod(int value, bool option, string message)
{
    value = 1;
    // More code...
}
```

However, Visual Studio complains at the following (as expected):

```
private int _myProperty;
public int MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _myProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        int value = 0;
        _myProperty = value;
    }
}
```

This leads me to believe that "value" is treated as a keyword (or not) depending on the context. I am fairly new to C# and, as far as I know, I have not seen context-specific keywords in other languages.

**The question:**
Is it always safe to use "value" as a variable name outside of a property setter? If not, when can this be done safely? And, is this often considered bad practice?

*I was surprised that I wasn't able to find this question already asked on SO, and I suspect that someone has asked it before. However, it is difficult to search for because so many posts have "variable" and "identifier" in the title. I was unable to find information about this on MSDN.*

**EDIT:** The last question is meant to ask if it is *often* or *commonly* frowned upon. It has been changed to reflect this.

Comment: `value` is already defined, so you can't redefine it in a property setter. Its not a keyword, its syntactic sugar by the compiler when it creates the method stubs for the setter property. It turns out something like `setMyProperty(int value) { your setter here }`

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) from MSDN might help you `The set accessor resembles a method whose return type is void. It uses an implicit parameter called value, whose type is the type of the property.`. It's not a keyword, it's an implicit parameter

Comment: Aside from "value" being a rather non-descriptive term, the reason why value is reserved inside of a parameter's setter, is because value is already defined for the scope of the setter: it's the value being set. It's relatively safe in most places, aside from setters, but discouraged due to being a very ambiguous term with no meaning in and of itself.

Comment: @willaien, good point re it being a poor choice of variable name.

Comment: @MattBurland, you final question, re is it good practice, risks this becoming a subjective question. FWIW though, I'd suggest it's bad practice, simply because "value" conveys no real meaning as to the variable's purpose.

Comment: @DavidArno: You tagged the wrong Matt, but FWIW, I agree that it's becoming subjective, but in a local variable, as in for example, a loop where the meaning of `value` is pretty obvious, I don't think it's a great sin.  And in some cases, for example imagine a function called `SquareRoot`, calling the parameter to it `value` would seem to be, if not the best, one of the best choices.

Comment: @MattBurland, sorry about that and fair point respectively :)

Comment: @DavidArno: I agree that asking whether it is considered poor practice could make the question subjective. By the last question, I meant to ask if it is *commonly* considered bad practice, because some things are widely frowned upon. This is (arguably) objective.

Comment: @MattMartin, Given the quality of answers you've received, I'm going to agree with you on this occasion :)

Comment: Context-specific keywords are a relatively common thing in C#. LINQ query syntax is another example.

Comment: There's quite a few context keywords in C# (and it's not exclusively a C# feature either) - off the top of my head, `yield`, `await`, `from` (and all the other LINQ keywords), `this` (used in extension method declaration), `var`, `dynamic` and `async`. In general, C# tries extremely hard to remain backwards compatible (ie. C# 1 code should still compile in C# 5), so every time they add a new keyword, it *has* to be a context keyword. I assume this also holds for the new keywords like `nameof`, though I haven't tested those yet.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's what [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) says:

> The set accessor resembles a method whose return type is void. It uses an implicit parameter called value, whose type is the type of the property.

The properties are basically syntactic sugar that avoids you having to write a lot of `get_Bar` and `set_Bar` methods (note: there are some other advantages too, the CLR knows it's a property). For example, if you have a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private int _bar;
    public int Bar
    {
        get { return _bar; }
        set { _bar = value; }
    }
}
```

It'll generate IL (for the setter) that looks something like this:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname 
            instance void  set_Bar(int32 'value') cil managed
    {
      // 
      .maxstack  8
      IL_0000:  nop
      IL_0001:  ldarg.0
      IL_0002:  ldarg.1
      IL_0003:  stfld      int32 Program/Foo::_bar
      IL_0008:  ret
    } // end of method Foo::set_Bar
```

The thing to note here is that the `set_Bar` method takes a parameter called `value`. So not only does it "resemble" a method whose return type is void with a parameter called `value`, it actually is that.

So you can't use `value` for something else in a setter, obviously.

Now should you use it elsewhere? It depends. If it's obvious what it's referring to in the context where you are using it then sure. If `value` is ambiguous in a particular context then use something more explicit.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a1khb4f8(v=vs.140).aspx):

> The contextual keyword value is used in the set accessor in ordinary property declarations.

It makes no mention of any other context where `value` is considered a keyword, so aside from a setter, *or anywhere else where it might have been defined already*, you should be fine using `value`. Is it bad practice? Not as a rule, no more than any other potentially ambiguous variable name.

Edit: One place where I think having `value` as a name would be really problematic would be as a field (or worse a property) in a class. For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    private int value;
    public int Value
    { 
        get { return value; }
        set { value = value; }    // which `value` are you setting? and to what?
    }
 }
```

Now you could remove the ambiguity here with `this.value = value`, but it still ugly and it seems better to me to just use a different name for you field.

Comment: If I remember correctly in C# 1  you could not use `value` as a variable name at all regardless of context. It changed at some point down the road.

Comment: @zespri pragmatically, you still shouldn't either. I've seen code refer to a parameter `currentValue` that is actually a reference type. It made me feel itchy.

Comment: Agreed.  Just because C# lets you use certain of its reserved words as identifiers in certain circumstances doesn't mean you should.  I would avoid using any context-sensitive words as identifiers even when it's technically allowed just on principle.  There's only ~100 keywords in C#, it shouldn't be too hard to find appropriate variable names that don't conflict with any of them.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: This is, of course, into the realm of being opinion based, but I'm not as against using `value`. For example, if you had a function called `SquareRoot` that took a single parameter and returned the square root of the number, what would you call that parameter? `value` seems like an perfectly appropriate name in that case.

Comment: @MattBurland Apparently MS thinks [the parameter should be called `d`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt(v=vs.110).aspx) (presumably for "double")... but they use `value` for other functions [such as Abs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2yzeea2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Sabre: Ha. I should have bothered to go look and use `Abs` as my example instead! IMHO, `d` is a much worse parameter name than `value` for that function.

Comment: @MattBurland Definitely a pretty baffling choice. Personally I prefer `number` (or `num`) in this context since it's still clear and relevant and is also never a keyword in C#

Answer (score 22):

In a property setter, the variable name `value` is reserved. It is used as the name of the variable which can be assigned to a backing field.

> The question: Is it always safe to use "value" as a variable name outside of a property setter? If not, when can this be done safely? And, is this considered bad practice?

It's only reserved in the property setter. It's a very generic name, but it can often be the best description of the variable you are working with.

[MSDN info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/a1khb4f8.aspx)

Comment: IMO the "`value` keyword" reference you've linked is a far better answer to the question "is `value` OK to use elsewhere?" than the "using properties" reference linked in the accepted answer, which can only answer the question "is `value` not OK to use in properties?"

Answer (score 8):

It is fine to use `value` as an identifier anywhere outside a `set` accessor. The [C# Language Specification (linking old version)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664452.aspx) says:

> Since a set accessor implicitly has a parameter named `value`,
>   it is a compile-time error for a local variable or constant
>   declaration in a set accessor to have that name.

The Word `value` is not (and was never) a full keyword in C#, even if it has had this special use in setters ever since C# 1.

See [`value` (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1khb4f8.aspx) for more.

Of course, if you have a field (class-level variable) called `value` and you want to access it from within a `set` accessor, use `this.value` (or `NameOfYourType.value` for `static` fields).

---

For a list of real keywords and contextual "keywords", also see [C# Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

C# [has lots of contextual keywords](http://ericlippert.com/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords/). The main reason for them in new versions of the language is to avoid breaking changes with existing compiling code. Contextual keywords lets them add new semantics, without breaking code that was previously valid.

As mentioned in Eric's article, you can always use `@` as a prefix to be able to use a keyword as an identifier. I think the main advantage of that is the ability to interoperate with other libs that may have been developed in other CLR language with a different set of keywords, where a C# keyword (either reserved or contextual) may not be a keyword in that other language.

Comment: Mostly correct, but: `value` was in the C# language from the very first version, so the reason why it is not a keyword is **not** to avoid breaking changes. And you cannot use `@value` inside a `set` accessor to refer to some other `@value` than `value`. So the `@` "escape" is not relevant here. The word `value` is already an identifier, so applying a `@` to turn it into an identifier changes nothing.

Comment: Didn't meant to imply that `value` was a new keyword in some version of the language, and for that reason had to be contextual. My answer about contextual keywords was for the "I have not seen context-specific keywords in other languages" part.

Comment: I had not tried the `@` to escape the `value` keyword before. Now that you mentioned it, it makes a lot of sense, knowing how the properties are compiled to get/set methods. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As other have answered value is reserved for properties, however value it is not reserved specifically for methods, therefore, you can use value for variables everywhere other then properties setter

However if you set value in the get it will work just fine.

Good

```
public int MyProperty { get { int value = 0; return value; }}
```

Not good

```
public int MyProperty { get { ... } set { int value = 0; _MyProperty = value }}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# has two types of keywords: global keywords and contextual keywords.

Global keywords may never be used as identifiers. Contextual keywords are reserved only in certain circumstances. For example, you may use most LINQ keywords as variable or method names, when the compiler sees that the code is not a query.

**value** is reserved only in property setters as the parameter name. Everywhere else you may use it as an identifier, and it often makes sense. I think it's unlikely that this keyword's context will expand, because a lot of programs use it as a parameter name and nobody likes breaking changes.